# Append sources of multiple photos selected with <input type="file"> to list so they can be displayed with imglist[i] before uploading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React application and would like to setState to photo sources before uploading. I'm trying to do it with this function here:

```
const getImagesHandler = () => {
    let fileinput = document.getElementById("file-input");
    let files = fileinput.files;
    let photos = [];
    let i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<files.length;i++){
        photos.push(files[i].SOURCE??);
    }
    this.setState({Photos: photos)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getImagesHandler = () => {
        let photos = [];
        var fi = document.getElementById('file-input'); // GET THE FILE INPUT.

        // VALIDATE OR CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
        if (fi.files.length > 0) {
            // RUN A LOOP TO CHECK EACH SELECTED FILE.
            for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
                console.log(fi.files.item(i));
                photos.push(fi.files.item(i));
            }
        }
        this.setState({ Photos: photos})
```